# DialogResult handling

Tags: c#, wpf, progressdialog, dialogresult

I have a question about accessing dialogdata from wpf/ I have a `ProgressDialog :System.Windows.Window`
And I am calling it in OnButtonClick like this:

```
        void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog("");
            //dlg.AutoIncrementInterval = 0;
            LibWrap lwrap = new LibWrap();
            DoWorkEventHandler handler = delegate { BitmapFrame bf = lwrap.engine(frame); };
            dlg.CurrentLibWrap = lwrap;
            dlg.AutoIncrementInterval = 100;
            dlg.IsCancellingEnabled = true;
            dlg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            dlg.RunWorkerThread(0, handler);
}
```

The question is - how to check in this function(OnButtonClick) if the DialogResult is OK (in other words - how to access dlg's inner fields after it finish execution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DialogResult` usually is no inner field but a rather public property, so `dlg.DialogResult` should be fine (given that it inherits from Window), you will need to cast it to a bool.

I do not see you open the window anywhere, if you use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) the return value is automatically the `DialogResult` and the calling thread  blocks until it gets closed.

```
var result = (bool)dlg.ShowDialog();
```

If you need a non-modal dialog you can use [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) subscribe to the [`Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event and check the `DialogResult` there.

```
dlg.Closed += (_,__) =>
{
    var result = (bool)dlg.ShowDialog();
    // Do something with it.
}
dlg.Show();
```

Of course the dialog needs to set the property in either case. Default actions like Alt+f4 set it to false.

Comment: ShowDialog is in RunWorkerThread ->return ShowDialog() ?? false;

Comment: it returns bool but I tried: if(dlg.RunWorkerThread(0, handler)) But my data was still in process - and i couldnot get an access

Comment: Why would you do any kind of test? Just wait for the dialog to raise an event instead.

Comment: I have tried  dlg.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(dlg_Closing);
            dlg.Closed +=new EventHandler(dlg_Closed); Non of function dlg_Closed or dlg_Closing was hited after progress dialog was collapsed (not by error)  (

Comment: collapsed or actually closed? Also if the dialog was actually closed the method *should* be called, i have no idea what you are doing there...

Comment: closed. This is strange but that is. May be I must try to pass this events myself.

Comment: I have found bug. I have subscribes on this events AFTER the dialog has to close(( when I moved dlg.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(dlg_Closing); right after ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(""); all seems to be working... Thank you for your answers